# Enviar json, gson por medio de KSoap en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, json, gson, ksoap

Pasa que estoy intentando enviar lo que tiene un archivo Json a un WebService hecho en C#, debo de enviarle la cadena que contiene el archivo Json desde android, lo que debo de mandar en este caso es la variable "guardado" que la creo así a partir de una Shared Preference

```
carrito=getSharedPreferences("carrito",MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String guardado = carrito.getString("cesta","");
        ////gson convierte el elemento guardado a un arraylist
 final Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Elemento>>(){}.getType();
cesta=gson.fromJson(guardado,type);
```

los datos que contiene esa variable son:

```
[
  {
    "cantidad": 3,
    "monto": 27.96,
    "nombre": "Churrasco",
    "precio": 6.99
  }
]
```

Este es mi código:

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Thread tr= new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
                            String URL = "http://192.168.43.57/Publicaciones/WebServiceCarrito.asmx";
                            String METHOD_NAME = "insertarJson";
                            String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/insertarJson";
                            SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP=null;
                            SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

                            request.addProperty("json", guardado);


                            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
                            envelope.dotNet=true;
                            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                            HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                            try {
                                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                                final SoapObject soap = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"¡Escoge lo que quieras!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                });
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                };
                tr.start();
```

Al ejecutar la función no pasa nada, android no envía los datos, probé la conexión y funciona correctamente. Quisiera saber si hay un método de envío y si es así cuál es.

Comment: Revisaste el LogCat?

Comment: Qué es eso amigo? Soy nuevo en esto de Android. :/

Comment: Ok, no te preocupes, si deseas encontrar errores rápidamente y perder segundos en lugar de horas o días es muy importante el uso del LogCat  , da una revisada al documento: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat 
Cuando ejecutes tu aplicación y esta marque error o se cierre, revisa que mensajes se despliegan, los errores son los de color rojo, revisalo y si necesitas ayuda comenta. @YonatanUlisesSegura

Comment: Ya estuve revisando el LogCat y no arroja ningún error, pero no envía ningún dato :/ solo no pasa nada

Comment: Revisando muy detenidamente encontré que tenía dos metedos de OnClickListener para mi botón, eliminé uno y todo funcionó correctamente :D pero muchísmas gracias por tu ayuda @Jorgesys